# Installing an SSL/TLS cert on a load balancer that is Stripe compliant

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, stripe-payments

firstly this is my first experience installing an SSL/TLS cert so please forgive my ignorance/innocence on the topic.

I have an EC2 instance set up with a load balance running in the EU (Ireland) region, unfortunately the AWS Certificate Manager isn't available yet (any plans to introduce it there?? :) ), so I am getting a cert and installing it myself. My website will be using Stripe, which [says you have to use SSl](https://stripe.com/docs/security/ssl) and I am just wondering if the [positive SSL from Comodo](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/domain-validation.aspx) will be enough? I don't really have the cash for $100+ EV cert at the moment. I know that might be a question for Stripe, but someone might know.

The part that I am wondering about AWS is, if I get the positive SSL cert and upload it through the AWS console to IAM (by adding a HTTPS listener to the load balancer), do I then have to install the certificate on my actual EC2 instance also, or is just doing it once through the console enough? Does that just mean that the https will be from a users browser to my load balancer, and not from my load balancer to my server? If I am going to have payments through my site is this a bad set up? Should I be getting a different cert?

Is just installing the positiveSSL cert through the console enough that my site will now be accessible through https://example.com and it doesn't have the green lock, or will it still be http://example.com and the HTTPS stuff just goes on in the background.

Sorry if this is an annoying question / doesn't make sense. I am just trying to wrap my head around it all. Thanks!

Comment: any ssl cert will work and its fine going in the load balancer (though that does, in theory, open you up to an attack between your load balancer and the ec2 instance, though in reality its pretty impossible to do. You'd want to redirect non https to https

Answer (score 0):

[Stripe details this well](https://stripe.com/docs/security/ssl):

> Do I need to use SSL/TLS on my payment pages?
>   Yes ... It's more secure

and

> What if I don't want to set up SSL/TLS yet?
>   You can test your page--**but not live transactions**--before installing your SSL/TLS certificate. You don't need to enable HTTPS until you're ready to go live.
>   To test live transactions without your own SSL/TLS certificate, you could host your site with a provider that provides a secure subdomain. For example, Heroku allows you to host at https://yourapp.heroku.com.

Ultimately, your site doesn't need to be PCI compliant, as Stripe handles all the credit card information. Clearly they don't set a "stripe compliant" standard for the SSL cert.